# A reliable way to remove consecutive appearances of a substring

Tags: c#, strings

I'm attempting to write a piece of code that is supposed to remove consecutive appearances of a `string` (not a single character) in a `StringBuilder`.
It's **extremely** important that the method works well and does not remove or change anything that it shouldn't. Solid performance is a secondary requirement.

for example:

```
Input: "xxxxABCxxxxABCABCxxxxABABCxxABCABCABC"
Remove consecutive: "ABC"

Output: "xxxxABCxxxxABCxxxxABABCxxABC"
```

I've written a method that does this and testing shows that it works as expected, but it will be catastrophic if I use it and it results in changing the `StringBuilder` in an unexpected way - that's why I want another opinion on whether my code is really 'safe' in all cases:

```
public static void RemoveConsecutive(this StringBuilder sb, string value)
{
    if (sb == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sb");
    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    if (value == string.Empty)
        throw new ArgumentException("value cannot be an empty string.", "value");

    bool justRemoved = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length - value.Length; i++)
    {
        if (justRemoved || Util.ExistsAt(sb, i, value))
        {
            if (Util.ExistsAt(sb, i + value.Length, value))
            {
                sb.Remove(i, value.Length);
                justRemoved = true;
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                justRemoved = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Checks if the provided string appears in the StringBuilder at the specified index
public static bool ExistsAt(StringBuilder sb, int startIndex, string str)
{
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex >= sb.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", "startIndex must be a valid index in the provided StringBuilder.");
    if (startIndex + str.Length > sb.Length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != sb[i + startIndex])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

While this piece of code does something rather trivial, I just want another set of eyes to look at it and possibly find faults I could not. Again, any sort of unexpected behavior might be catastrophic.

Comment: If it's so important, have you written unit tests for it?

Comment: @svick Yes. I have tested it rather extensively, but what I'm scared of is some sort of 'edge case' that I might not come across in my tests.

Comment: You state the problem as "remov[ing] consecutive appearances of a substring" and give an example of `"xxxxABCxxxxABCABCxxxxABABCxxABCABCABC" ->
"xxxxABCxxxxABCxxxxABABCxxABC"`.  But (replacing your `x`s with digits for visibility) shouldn't that result be `0123ABC45678901ABABC23`?

Comment: @RossPatterson The additional instances of `ABC` you removed were not consecutive.

Comment: @svick I beg to differ.  "ABC" -> "ABC", "ABCABC" -> "", "ABABC" -> "ABABC", "ABCABCABC" -> "".  The second and fourth cases have consecutive ABCs.  The example suggests eliminating groups of doubled ABCs, which is not the same thing.  Hence my question.

Comment: @RossPatterson Sorry, you're right, I looked incorrectly at the original string. I think what the code should do is that if you have several consecutive instances, remove *all but one*.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks like it does exactly what you want to me.

Some notes:

1. `StringBuilder` methods (which you're emulating by using an extension method) return the modified `StringBuilder`, so they can be used in a [fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) manner. You should probably do the same.
2. I don't like changing the index of a `for` loop. Especially since `i--` means “stay at the same index”, I think that's confusing. You should use a `while` loop instead.
3. You can shorten your code by quite a bit by using `Regex`:

   ```
   public static string RemoveConsecutive(string text, string value)
   {
       // validation omited

       string regex = string.Format(@"({0})+", Regex.Escape(value));
       return Regex.Replace(text, regex, match => value);
   }
   ```

   Shorter code is usually less error prone. But in this case, I'm not so sure about that, because there are some intricacies in this code:

   1. Calling `Escape()` is crucial if `value` contains some regex special characters (e.g. `*`).
   2. If the `value` was used directly as the replacement (instead of a delegate), it wouldn't work correctly if it contained any [substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) (e.g. `$0`).

Comment: Indeed, this would seem to be one of those occasions when using regular expressions does not give you two problems.